# iOS13 automagically remembers app permissions after deleting app

Tags: ios, permissions

Interestingly iOS remembers my camera authorization after deleting the entire app from the phone. As far as I remember this has not been the case earlier.

This what I did: install an app (run debug mode). Grant permission to use camera. Delete app. Install again (run again). Phone wont ask for permission the second time.

Is this the intended behaviour? How am I supposed to test permission request/denial now?

Comment: How did you request the camera permission?

Comment: Does it really matter? Why does it remember between deletes?

Comment: It matters, app is not remembering your permissions

Comment: This what I expected. Tried several times. I delete the whole app. Reinstall and the camera stream is shown without the consent of the user.

Comment: and it is not happening on any other version of iOS?

Comment: when you open settings app and find your app are there your permission settings all the time?

Comment: Guys I think I found it. When I record the screen it does not show for the second time. Hold on. (EDIT: nope it is not the reason)

Comment: Wrong: it has no relationship. This is crazy. Anyway: the expected way that it won't remember? True?

Comment: @Lu_ do you mean after delete?

Comment: after, before and right after new install

Comment: It disappears after delete. Shown after install with the OLD settings. So if I deny prior to delete it remains denied. If I enable it stays enabled.